# Old fantasy image depicting a kid in a space suit building sandcastles on the moon

Tags: object-identification

I'm looking for an old image seen in the 1980s. Stylistically, it looks like it could have been by Boris Vallejo or Julie Bell (both famous for heroic fantasy covers and pictures), but as far as I know they are not the artists.

It did depict a kid (a girl I think) in a space suit, doing sandcastles (with a plastic bucket) on the moon.

Since this happened 35 years ago, I could be mistaken with the style, but I saw it at the same time as other Vallejo pics, on a slide show for the Amiga or Atari ST.

Does anyone know this one?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That's Michael Whelan's work "The Ultimate Sandbox":

https://www.michaelwhelan.com/galleries/ultimate-sandbox/

[image]http://sf.co.ua/13/05/wallpaper-2788939.jpg

Comment: that was amazingly quick! thanks Mark! Thinking of it: is that the only one image like this? in my (very possibly flawed) memory, the girl was seen from the side and holding the bucket in the hands. Could someone else have copied that concept? or is my memory playing a trick on me (it was 320x200 pic back then too)

Comment: @Thomas Possibly redrawn/reimagined as a 320x200 pic by someone, rather than digitized?

Comment: @mattdm: I think this is very very likely, since the theme was identical, but the picture rather different! I didn't think of following that lead at all; thanks!